# AngularJS - De qué forma puedo obtener los parametros y valores de la url

Tags: angularjs

Con Javascript tengo:

```
function getUrlVars(){
  var vars = [], hash;
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(
    window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1
  ).split('&');

  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

Cómo podría ser con AngularJS?

Comment: Puedes agregar como tienes definidos tus states

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo el servicio que utilices para hacer routing ($routeprovider o $stateprovider) vas a poder acceder a esos valores de distintas maneras.

- Si utilizas ($stateprovider) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Podes acceder a tus parametros haciendo: $state.params

- Si utilizas ($routeprovider) 
  Podes acceder a tus parametros haciendo : $location.search();
  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 1):

Con el $routeProvider, si tienes esta URL definida:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/:param1/:param2/:param3', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/template.html',
        controller: 'ControllerCtrl'
    })
```

En el controlador puedes recibirlo como:

```
angular.module('test').controller('ControllerCtrl', function (...) {

      var param1 = $routeParams.param1,
          param2 = $routeParams.param2,
          param3 = $routeParams.param3;
```